# Replace letters but NOT special characters and capital letters in strings (Java)

Tags: java, string, replace

I am able to replace lower case letters to next letter. Special Character and Upper Case letters shouldn't change but I can't figure out how.

```
/** Return s but with each occurrence of a letter in 'a'..'y'
 * replaced by the next letter and 'z' replaced by 'a'
 *
 * Examples: nextChar("") = ""
 * nextChar("abcz") = "bcda"
 * nextChar("1a$b") = "1b$c"
 * nextChar("AB") = "AB"
 * nextChar("love") = "mpwf"   */
public static String nextLetter(String s) {
    // TODO 3
    String next = "";
    for (char x: s.toCharArray()) {
        next += Character.toString((char)(((x - 'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a'));
    }
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an if statement to check if the character is a lowercase letter and then promote it to the next letter.  The `Character` type already has a `Character.isLowerCase()` to check if the character is a lowercase letter.

You can also do a range check like `if ('a' <= character && character <= 'z')` to check if the letter is lowercase.

When you determine the letter is lowercase, promote it to the next letter (Also check if the character passes 'z', and roll it back to 'a' if it does) and append it to the result. If it's not a lowercase letter, you just append it to the result.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(nextLetter("abcz1a$bABlove"));
    }

    private static String nextLetter(String data) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            char character = data.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLowerCase(character)) {
                character++;
                // Account for rollover on 'z'
                if (character == '{') {
                    character = 'a';
                }
            } 

            result += character;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Result

```
bcda1b$cABmpwf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if condition to check if a letter is lowercase.
Also, I've used Java 8 lambda function to iterate through characters in the string.

```
public static String nextLetter(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    s.chars().forEach(c -> {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            sb.append((char) (((c - 'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a'));
        } else {
            sb.append((char)c);
        }
    });
    return sb.toString();
}
```